# Keycloak and Go with gocloak - Cannot decode tokens

Tags: docker, go, authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am trying to do some testing using keycloak and go in a local docker setup. Currently, I have a keycloak container (with a postgres backend) running on 8080. I set this up with a client that has service account access, and have my ClientID, client secret, realm etc all in a config file.

I then have a go API running in docker as well. In this go API, at startup I create a new gocloak client and hold reference to it:

```
client := gocloak.NewClient(host)
log.Infof("clientid: %s pw: %s // realm: %s", clientId, clientSecret, realm)
ctx := context.Background()
tkn, err := client.LoginClient(ctx, clientId, clientSecret, realm)
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("error occurred connecting to keycloack: %s", err)
}
```

The value of host above is:

```
http://keycloak:8080
```

as the docker container running keycloak is just called keycloak. Obviosuly if i Try and use localhost:8080 here, it fails because we are inside a container.

And then as a middleware on any calls coming in to this service's routes, I use that client and check:

```
authHeader := c.GetHeader("Authorization")
parts := strings.Split(authHeader, " ")
if len(parts) != 2 {
    c.AbortWithStatus(401)
    return
}

ctx := context.Background()
kc.Logger.Infof("Incoming auth header: %s", parts[1])
token, err := kc.Auth.RetrospectToken(ctx, parts[1], kc.ClientId, kc.ClientSecret, kc.Realm)
if err != nil {
    kc.Logger.Errorf("error occurred parsing token: %s", err)
}
kc.Logger.Infof("token: %v", token)
```

In order to test this, what I have been doing is starting up all the services, and then navigating to:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/dev/account/#/
```

and then I sign in with google (an account I have already set up on keycloak earlier).
Then, using the developer tools in the browser, im finding a network call that contains

```
KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiaSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICIwMTg3MzU0MS03YmE3LTQ0MmQtYjMxOC0zMjBhYmIzYjNmMmIi<AND_SO_ON>; Version=1; Path=/auth/realms/dev/; SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly
```

From this i extract just the token, and then use that as a Bearer token in a postman call to my go back end.

The problem I am having is that, in step 1 when I log in my service account, if i retrospect the token returned there, I see the struct I'd expect with the oauth2 token values.
This middleware, when it retrospects the incoming tokens I give it, i just get

```
{
    active: false
}
```

every time.

I am not entirely sure where I have gone wrong here. I have read a number of posts that say the host has to be the EXACT SAME between the acquire token, and the endpoint used to inspect it, which leads me to beleive that since I get a token from:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/dev/account/#/
```

but am decoding it on a host inside the container thats called:

```
http://keycloack:8080
```

That this may be my problem? Is this accurate? or have I gone wrong somewhere else?

If this IS in fact the problem, how can I go about solving this? I can't get a token from the internal docker name from the outside in order to test calls going in to my API, and I cannot use "localhost" inside the go container to match where i get it from as this wont resolve.

How can I either get a hostname i can access from both inside and outside the container?

Or, as mentioned, have I gone wrong somewhere else entirely?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Hello @aescript. May I ask you, do you have a sample to share on how to setup authorisation flow using gocloak? Cheers!